# Autofocus only working on page refresh

Tags: html, forms, autofocus

I have a form which is in a popup, I've set the autofocus attribute `autofocus="autofocus"` but it is not focusing when the form loads however it will focus if you refresh the page. The form is inserted into a `div`.

Form Sample:

```
First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" class="userField" autofocus="autofocus" id="firstNameUserField" value="<?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['firstname'])){
       echo trim($_SESSION['firstname']);
    }
  ?>">
```

Div form is inserted into:

```
  <div class="main">
    <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="detail_form"></a>
    <div class="popup">
      <div id="detailFormPopup"></div>
      <a class="close" id="logClose"href="#close"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Form is shown if user is logged in and clicks their username:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
          echo "<a href='#detail_form' class='navlinks' id='navUser'>".$_SESSION['username']."</a></h3>";
        }
```

Comment: When you say `popup`, do you mean an actual popup, a new window? Or a simple Javascript dialog?

Comment: I'm using a jQuery plug in SimpleModal to create a popup.
http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autofocus` will apply only for elements initially in the page, not elements loaded with Javascript.

You can force the focus in the Javascript code that you use to render the SimpleModal, add it to the `onShow` event:

```
$('#firstNameUserField').focus();
```

You didn't include the Javascript used to open the popup in your question, so this is just a general example:

```
$("#popupEl").modal({onShow: function (dialog) {
 $('#firstNameUserField').focus();
}});
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this with the plugin, does your function need to put in the plugin js?

Comment: @Colin747 According you the documentation, you are supposed to call the `modal()` function on the element you want to show as a dialog. You surely do something to make the dialog appear. Add it to your question and I'll be able to make my answer more specific.

Comment: I'm loading  `$("#detailFormPopup").load("external/userDetailsForm.php");` on `document.ready` when the user clicks on the link it calls `href='#detail_form'` which loads 

`<div class="main">
        <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="detail_form"></a>
        <div class="popup">
          <div id="detailFormPopup"></div>
          <a class="close" id="logClose"href="#close"></a>
        </div>`

Answer (score 3):

To solve the issue of "Autofocus only working on page refresh"

Do the following changes in your files:-

```
//In module.ts file 

import { AutofocusModule } from 'angular-autofocus-fix';

@NgModule({
imports: [
AutofocusModule
],

//In package.json file add the dependencies as:- 

    "dependencies": {
    "angular-autofocus-fix": "^0.1.0"
}
```