# Autofocus on input generated by jquery has stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where there is an img that acts as a button: when I click on it, the row is cloned and inserted into the table.
I would like to make sure that when I add a new row it is focus.
Initially this code worked and the last line created was in focus but now it has stopped working.
Before writing the question I tried various solutions but they didn't work. I was tempted to add the html autofocus attribute to the last line and remove it from the previous one when I created another line but I don't think it's a valid method.
This is the html code of the line:

```
     <tr>
        <td  class="col-2 align-middle">
            <label for="Server" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo $title_Server?>">Server</label>
        </td>
        <td class="col-8 align-middle">
            <input name="Server" class="form-control" type="text" disabled>
        </td>
        <td class="col-2 align-middle my-auto">
            <img class="aggiungiRiga" src="img/add.svg" />
            <img class="modificaRiga" src="img/pencil.svg" />
            <img class="cancellaRiga"  src="img/delete.svg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

This is the code jquery / js manages the cloning of the line.

```
$('.aggiungiRiga').on('click', function (){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr").clone().insertAfter('form > table > tbody > tr:last').find('input').attr('autofocus');//.find('input').focus();

    $('form > table > tbody > tr:last td input').prop('disabled', false);
    $('form > table > tbody > tr:last td:last img:nth-child(1)').hide();//css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('form > table > tbody > tr:last td:last img:nth-child(2)').hide();//css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('form > table > tbody > tr:last td:last img:nth-child(3)').attr('class', 'eliminaRiga');
})
```

Comment: I recommend using jQuery's [focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) after enabling the input. The [`autofocus` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefautofocus) only focuses the input "when the page is loaded". See [Adding autofocus attribute when input is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015515/adding-autofocus-attribute-when-input-is-hovered) and [Autofocus only working on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800058/autofocus-only-working-on-page-refresh/15800192#15800192).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the element can't be focused if it is disabled so I would advice you to try this code in your js

```
$('.aggiungiRiga').on('click', function (){
    event.preventDefault();
    var x=$(this).closest("tr").clone().insertAfter('form > table > tbody > tr:last').find('input');//.find('input').focus();
        x.prop('disabled',false)
    x.focus()
    //$('form > table > tbody > tr:last td input').prop('disabled', false);
    $('form > table > tbody > tr:last td:last img:nth-child(1)').hide();//css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('form > table > tbody > tr:last td:last img:nth-child(2)').hide();//css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('form > table > tbody > tr:last td:last img:nth-child(3)').attr('class', 'eliminaRiga');
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly.
I think my code didn't work because focus () was applied before the disabled was removed.